# Received a document in Adobe Photoshop, how do I scroll or view other pages?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm stuck on the main page. it's adobe Photoshop CS6

I received a multipage legal document in Adobe Photoshop and don't know how to navigate through the document past the first page

Comment: I think there's been some misunderstanding with either the sender, you, or both. While the file is opening in Photoshop, you haven't clarified if it's file type is PSD (which is PhotoShops own). If it is, it can't have multiple pages, only multiple layers. This would be a very unorthodox way of sending multiple pages (as multiple layers) so I'm assuming there's been a misunderstanding. PhotoShop can also open many other file types and I'm wondering if it's opening one of these instead. For instance, it can open PDF documents for good reasons but it should never be used to read PDF documents

Comment: It would be very unusual to receive a legal document as a Photoshop file. It would be more likely to be a PDF, not a PSD. I suggest you check the document format again.  Photoshop is not a PDF viewer.

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop does not support "pages" in the traditional sense. There are applications such as Graphic Converter that *will* support multi-page raster files. Photoshop just isn't one of them.

You can try choosing `Window > Layers` from the menu to open the **Layers Panel**. If that contains more than 1 layer, you can click the little eyeball icon next to the layer to hide/how that layer. That *might* allow you to see other "pages". It's really impossible to say for certain without seeing the document structure.

Another option may be to try opening the document using Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

As always.. asking the person who sent you the file how you are expected to view it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Billi Kerr, it is probably a pdf and for some reason, you are trying to use Photoshop to open it. Check the extension of the file. If it is still a PSD file the other person is sending a file in the wrong format.

There is a chance you are receiving a Tif file. That file can be somehow linked to be opened in Photoshop, but it is also a wrong format to use.

If you are using Windows, try to use IrfanView http://www.irfanview.com/, that is an image viewer. If the file has "true" multiple pages you can navigate inside it.